# time_zone is not getting saved in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I am making the user to select their time zone from a drop down depending on which time is set.

Using rails 2.3.9 and ruby 1.8.7
My code is done like this
 in application controller

before_filter :set_time_zone
  def set_time_zone
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if current_user
  end

in the view(haml)
f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sort

in user table
added time_zone as string

in environment.rb
config.gem = 'UTC'

But though drop down is appearing with time zones ...its not getting saved.

Answer (score 0):

The line in environment.rb should look like

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

Your form should look like:

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones %>
```